# para que serve o & no printf em C?

Tags: c

Opa, eai, queria saber como que funciona o & (e comercial), no caso do printf, no scanf eu sei, que ele leva a variável pra um endereço de memória, mas e no caso do printf? eu tenho esse programa aqui, e não sei muito bem a função desse &, só sei que sem ele, o programa não roda rs

```
char nome[30], sobrenome[20], ch;

printf("Informe seu nome: ");
scanf("%29[^\n]", nome);
int i;
for (i = 0; nome[i] != ' ' && nome[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    printf("%c", nome[i]); // Para mostrar o primeiro nome
}
printf("\nBoa noite, %s!\n", &nome[i+1]); // => nome == &nome[0]
system("Pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: Neste printf você está especificando o código de formato %s, isto é, deseja imprimir uma string. A string é identificada pelo endereço do caractere inicial e o final da string pelo caractere '\0'. Daí estar especificado &nome[i+1], isto é o endereço da posição i+1 de nome. Como no loop anterior a condição de permanência é nome[i] != ' ' && nome[i] != '\0' será impresso alguma coisa que faça sentido apenas se nome[i] == ' '.

Comment: Eu acho que entendi o que você quis dizer, vou fazer alguns testes aqui, valeu!!!

Comment: Uma situação de contorno para você testar: se o nome informado em sua entrada não tiver um espaço em branco seu programa imprimirá lixo de memória.

Comment: sim, eu acabei de fazer um teste, e realmente ele imprimiu lixo de memória, entendi!!!

Answer (score -4):

O & você utiliza no scanf e não no printf, ele é pra indicar que você vai mexer num local de memória.

Comment: mas nesse caso, sem esse & no printf, ele não roda o programa corretamente, alguma função ele deve fazer rs

Comment: É porque a sua variável no scanf está sem o &

Comment: A variavel é Char, isso se torna indiferente, ter ou não ter o &

Comment: Faz sentido a existência do & no printf e não faz sentido o uso do & comercial no scanf pois é a leitura de uma string.

Comment: Manda o erro pra gente aí

Comment: exatamente isso!

Comment: Nem sempre o `scanf` precisa do `&`, e o `printf` pode ter `&` sim: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50075252

Comment: na verdade ele tá dizendo que isso tá errado hkotsubo.

Comment: Para entender isso basta seguir os *links* da pergunta duplicata. O `&` nada tem a ver com o `scanf()` ou print()`, por isso falar sobre isso não fará chegar a lugar algum. A pergunta entende errado onde de fato está a questão e a resposta embarca nesse erro. Este operador só sobre um objeto acessado através de seu endereço, só isso, onde ele é usado é circunstancial. e nem deveria constar da pergunta ou resposta. Tem várias percepções erradas nos comentários também. Melhor estudar o assunto para entender.